# How to check if woocommerce order contains two certain categories for order status update

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently changing the order status of orders depending on the product ordered. I only have two categories that are used, however, I need to order status to be different if the order includes **both** categories.

Currently the code just checks for 'category1' and will change the status, else the status will be updated to 'status2'.

I've tried the following but unfortunately this didn't work. I've also tried both of the categories in an array.

```
if ( has_term( 'category1', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) && has_term( 'category2', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
 $order->update_status( 'status3' );
}
```

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items(); 
  foreach ( $items as $item ) {  
      if ( has_term( 'category1', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ){
      $order->update_status( 'status1' );  
      } 
else {
  $order->update_status( 'status2' );
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this.

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items(); 
$c1 = false; //boolean to check if your products exists in category1
$c2 = false; //same as above but for category2
foreach ( $items as $item ) {  //loop through each product of the order before changing order status.
  if ( has_term( 'category1', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ){
    $c1 = true;
    continue;
  } elseif( has_term( 'category2', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
    $c2 = true;
  }
}
if($c1 && $c2)//if both categories are true set status3
   $order->update_status( 'status3' );
elseif($c1)//if only c1 is true, set status1
   $order->update_status( 'status1' );
else //c1 wasnt true so c2 must be, set status2
   $order->update_status( 'status2' );
```